# Как импортировать таблицу SQLite с автоимкрементом

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Таблица с _ *id* **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT**

```
_id|NAME|ADDRESS
```

И файл импорта

```
???|Саша|Верхнепортовая, 51
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это общий алгоритм действий при копировании данных содержащих автоинкрементное поле. Как это применить с андройдом? - наверно там тоже можно писать запросы )

Если нет других таблиц с полями ссылающимися на это автоинкрементное поле (или других полей в этой таблице, ссылающихся на него) - то просто копирование: инструкция insert database.schema.table (fieds) select from ...
при этом в списке полей целевой таблицы и в селекте НЕ указываешь это автоинкрементное поле.
Все, закончили.

Дальше только если ...

Если же есть таблицы с полями ссылающимися на это поле - то придется сначала создать временную таблицу с двумя полями - старый и новый ID. Заполнить ее (пока только поле - 'старый ID') всех строк, которые планируется переносить (это 1 запрос insert-select) 
дальше основное копирование курсором, построчно + получение ID новой записи и сохранение его во временную таблицу (получение последнего ID - переменная @@identity, которую надо читать непосредственно после каждой операции вставки внутри курсора например: select @newid = @@identity )

После переноса основной таблицы - копируем ссылающиеся на неё (один запрос), при этом значение поля-ссылки меняем со старого на новое (конструкция insert-select и в селекте дополнительный join на временную таблицу со связью - поле-ссылка = 'старый id')

если же в основной переносимой таблице есть поле ссылающееся на автоинкрементный ID, тогда - во временной таблице нужно еще одно поле - 'старая ссылка на ID' (также предварительно сохраняем, в том же запросе, что и 'старый ID'). При основном копировании значение этого поля в целевой таблице заменяем каким-то любым существующим значением ID в новой таблице. После основного копирования одним запросом (с join к временной таблице - заменяем значение этой ссылки на актуальное новое из временной таблицы)

---

Если конфликтов ID не предполагается (например целевая таблица - пустая) и нужно копировать также связанные таблицы - то можно копировать без пересчета ключей. Просто временно отключить правило автоинкремента, скопировать как есть, с указанием всех полей. Потом включить это правило обратно:

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . ] table OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . ] table ON

Comment: аналогично, при наличии ссылок на автоинкрементные поля копируемых подчиненных таблиц надо поступать и глубже по иеархии таблиц, рекурсивно